# Centos 5.11 mysql-server 5.0.95 upgrade to mysql55w-server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Here's my thought process on my upgrade:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > backup.sql

service mysqld stop

yum remove mysql mysql-server

yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server

service mysqld start

mysql_upgrade
```

theoretically, I should be good after that right? Anything I'm missing here? I'm scared to death of this upgrade. All the ones I've been reading about are from 5.1 to 5.5, not 5.0.95.

Can someone confirm/deny I'm going about this ok, or am I missing some huge steps?

Comment: You left out reloading the data.  Also, Stored Routines are not dumped without an extra parameter.  And be cautious about not reloading the `mysql` database.

Comment: My idea behind the initial backup was just to save it in case of emergency. If I'm not mistaken, uninstalling and then installing the new version *shouldn't* erase the data directory. Hence the mysql_upgrade command. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Also, we don't have stored procedures on this DB, so that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: OK, don't reload the data.  But, instead, upgrade first to 5.1 and run its mysql_upgrade.  Then upgrade again, to 5.5 and run its mysql_upgrade.  That is, the accepted procedure is to step through each major cycle (5.1.xx being the only one between 5.0 and 5.5.)